# Global name error when importing class as wild card Python

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror, attributeerror

I am trying to make a multiple "page" GUI using tkinter and couldn't really find a good method. I resorted to using grid_forget and seperating the "pages" in methods and it works like a charm. However I am trying to seperate the methods into a seperate file to make everything a little cleaner but I keep getting a global name error upon trying to run one of the methods with all of the widgets from my main file/class.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Derek/PycharmProjects/whites/Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from screens import *
  File "C:\Users\Derek\PycharmProjects\whites\screens.py", line 4, in <module>
    import Main
  File "C:\Users\Derek\PycharmProjects\whites\Main.py", line 54, in <module>
    app = Application(master=main, w=main.winfo_width(), h=main.winfo_height())
  File "C:\Users\Derek\PycharmProjects\whites\Main.py", line 20, in __init__
    home_screen(self,True)
NameError: global name 'home_screen' is not defined
```

I also tried importing it such as `import screens` and tried to run `screens.home_screen(self,True)` and that yeilds

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'home_screen'
```

Even though it does

`Example Main.py`

```
from screens import *
import globals


class Application(tk.Frame):

    globals.init()


    def __init__(self, w, h, master=None):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.window_width = w
        self.window_height = h

        home_screen(self,True)
        query_screen(False)
        res_screen(False)
        settings_screen(False)
```

`screens.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
import globals
import Main


def home_screen(self, state):
     *define widgets for this "screen"
```

**[EDIT]**
Here is a copy of the full files.[screens](http://pastebin.com/v10rbynx) , [Main](http://pastebin.com/f7593NHg) , [globals](http://pastebin.com/K3F03Mnv)

**[EDIT: 2]**
So I changed the code around to try a different solution and it basically the same error. module object has no attribute if I attempt to convert the screens.py into a class and initialize it as an object but nothing. So I am guessing this means it is not python at all and more my project settings have somewhere gone askew

Comment: have you tried doing something like `import screens; print(screens.__file__)`? That would tell you whether or not its importing the screens module that you think it should be importing.

Comment: Just check and yes it is the right file.

Answer (score 0):

You define:

```
def home_screen(self, state):
```

but it's not in any class!

Remove the `self` from the function signature and call it using only `state` variable only

**EDIT:**

If you create main.py:

```
from screens import *

class Application():

    def __init__(self):
        home_screen(True)


# then later on
a = Application() # this will print 'True'
```

and in file screens.py:

```
def home_screen(state):
    print state
```

it will work (assuming both are in the same directory).

Comment: Again it didn't do anything. I am using 3.3 and cleared the pycache folder. I made an edit with the full files linked

Answer (score 0):

The solutions was to run the screens.py and not the main.py. Why that is I have no idea but it still ultimately fits my goal. If anyone would like to weigh in go for it.

**[EDIT]**

Final solution, change the way the program starts.It now runs just fine.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = tk.Tk()
    main.wm_title("White's Canoe Livery")
    main.state("zoomed")
    main.update()
    # print(main.winfo_width())
    app = Application(master=main, w=main.winfo_width(), h=main.winfo_height())
    app.mainloop()
```